# Could I say 'The concept is hard to digest' ?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Could I say 'The concept is hard to digest'? I want to express that this concept is hard to learn and understand

Comment: Probably... it might help if you could give us a bit more context. What are you talking about?

Comment: I was just learning a course, and found a concept hard to understand, then could I say 'this concept is hard to digest'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. This concept is hard to digest.
>      [digest](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digest)
>      : to think over and try to understand (news, information, etc.)

Yes, I feel like this something people might say. I certainly understood what you meant.

Some similar expressions are

> - [get head around](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+head+around)
>     to be able to understand something (usually negative)
>     *He's tried to explain the rules of the game dozens of times but I just can't get my head around them.*
> - [wrap my head around](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wrap_one%27s_head_around)
>     To come to a good understanding of
> - [wrap my brain around](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wrap%20my%20brain%20around%20it)
>     Make sense of